# PGP Encryption on csv file data generated using pyspark and write to Azure container

Tags: pyspark, encryption, pgp, openpgp

From the existing delta lake tables, few information is gathered and those are written as csv file in Azure container. The contents of the csv file need to be encrypted using PGP.
Please help on how to do this.

Comment: I'm not aware if you can use pyspark to do pgp encryption/decryption. You will either need to use python if the file is small < 1GB or you can even use bash script using the gpg tool. Depends what compute you are using to do the encryption.  bash script using gpg is easy can you can achieve the needful in a few steps. The receiver needs to provide the public key to you for encrypting.